# "Derivative" of function on set of measures

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, geometric-measure-theory

Across my studies I came across an object which could be thought of as a "derivative" of a function defined on a set of measures and I was looking for references to the matter (if any). Specifically, let $\mathscr{M}$ be the set of (finite) measures on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $P:\mathscr{M}\to\mathbb{R}$ be an arbitrary function. For every $\eta\in\mathscr{M}$ and $x\in \mathrm{Supp}(\eta)$ we can consider the limit
$$
\lim\limits_{\varepsilon\to 0}\frac{P(\eta_{\varepsilon})-P(\eta)}{\eta(B_{\varepsilon}(x))}
$$
where $B_{\varepsilon}(x)$ is the open ball of radius $\varepsilon$ centered in $x$ and $\eta_{\varepsilon}$ is the measure defined by $\eta_{\varepsilon}(A)=\eta(A)+\eta(A\cap B_{\varepsilon}(x))$. I am looking for references on the study of the previous limit (properties, conditions for its existence, etcetera) or another way of looking at it. I understand one could simply re-express the limit through a function $f:[0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(\varepsilon)=P(\eta_{\varepsilon})$ and then multiply/divide by the Lebesgue measure of $ B_{\varepsilon}(x)$ to sort of try to see this as a normal derivative multiplied by a Radon-Nikodym derivative, however I am not aware of the details necessary for carrying this out and it seems to me that work like this has already be done.

Thanks for any help you might provide.

Comment: What did this object relate to, in your studies?

Comment: I'm very curious about where you've come across this as it's piqued my interest

Comment: @FShrike it actually comes from some actuarial applications where basically one tries to find a probability measure $\eta$ that minimises the value of $P$ seen as a risk measure